# Come play with us!

Tags: riddle

> I like to collect severed heads, 
> They help me channel my emotions
>
> I tend to hurt people,
> So you better watch your steps
>
> So why won't you come and play with me?
> I'm kid friendly too.

Who or what am I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer might be :

> Lego

I like to collect severed heads, 
They help me channel my emotions

> The lego character heads are detatchable and come in a variety of expressions & emotions  [image: Lego Heads!]

I tend to hurt people,
So you better watch your steps

> I think we all know stepping on lego pieces is one of the most painful experiences know..

So why won't you come and play with me?
I'm kid friendly too.

> Well they are made for playing and i guess they are designed for kids !